# faster way to load Images on web page

Tags: php, html, css

Just wanna ask. why is this code loads slow.. as i observer. it waits for all the images to be available before showing it

```
 <ul> 
             <?php
                for($i = 0 $i < 40; $i++){
                        echo '<li><a href="javascript:;" >
                                <img src=" images/num/pref_img.name"/></a>

                            </li>';
                        }
             ?>
 </ul>
```

than this code. it loads images by images and doesn't wait for all the images to finish before showing it.

```
<?php
                for($i = 0 $i < 40; $i++){
                        echo '<a href="javascript:;" >
                                <img src=" images/num/pref_img.name"/></a>';
                        }
             ?>
```

can anyone give me an idea how load image faster? or to optimize the first code.

Comment: It's not the script, it's request to load the images from the server that is slow.

Comment: Are you outputting the same image 40 times? You could use caching to make it load faster

Comment: its a random image..i don't know but the second one loads the images asynchronously

Comment: what javascript do you have that's affecting the first instance?

Comment: I'll bet my bottom dollar that there's some javascript doing *something* to anything with a class of "secure", because nothing else you've tagged this question with has the slightest bit to do with how fast your images load. It's either JS, or your server is slow, or your images are too large.

Comment: i don't have a javascript on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your .JPG images as **Progressive**, this way the image placeholder will be there.
Your CSS will have the correct layout, and over time the quality will improve, instead of loading the image pixel by pixel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that your images are optimized and that they aren't bigger than they need to be.